# setOnCancel and setOnDimiss Listeners doesn't execute

Tags: android, dialog

## Face of Codes:

I have a n Object of Dialog that defined below.

```
dselect=new Dialog(SuraSurface.this);
    dselect.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dselect.setContentView(R.layout.dialogstatus);
    dselect.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new    ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

and I implemented Listeners for it below.

```
dselect.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
                Log.d("DIMISSED", "");
            }
        });
```

## Problem

```
setOnDimissListener
```

of dialog doesn't execute.

## Question

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: where do you call dselect.dismiss() ?

Comment: I don't call! It'll called when on back button clicked

Comment: Well I tried the same code you have and it's working. Maybe you're doing something elsewhere.

Comment: onCancel() will be called when you press back button. not onDismiss()

Comment: I guess this problem occured after when I clean my project!